# Can't track down cause of "Index was out of range" exception

Tags: c#, list

So, i have this frankenstein:

```
var unsorted = new List<(Hand, List<Card>)>();
```

And when I try to add smt like this:

```
unsorted.Add((hand, _tempList));
```

I receive and error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')

How to properly initialize this List if I do not know in advance how many items will be stored?

at the request of comments:

```
_tempList = IsStraightFlush(theValueHand);
            if (_tempList.Count == 5)
            {
                unsorted.Add((hand, _tempList));
                continue;
            }
```

A function from where i add a List to the Tuple

```
        private List<Card> IsStraightFlush(List<Card> hList)
        {
        var st = 0;
        _tempList.Clear();


        foreach (var t in hList)
        {
           ...
        }
        if (_tempList.Count < 5)
        {
            return new List<Card>();
        }

       hList = _tempList.ToList();
        _tempList.Clear();

        for (var i = 0; i < hList.Count - 2; i++)
        {
           ...
            if (st == 4)
            {
                _tempList.Add(hList[i + 1]);
                return _tempList;
            }
        }

        st = 0;
        _tempList.Clear();
        if (hList[0].Value == 13) //Ace through 5
            for (int i = hList.Count - 1, j = 0; i > 0; i--, j++)
            {
              ...
                if (st == 4)
                {
                    _tempList.Add(hList.First());
                    return _tempList.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList(); 
                }
            }
        return new List<Card>();
        }
```

And when i use it

```
resultHands.AddRange(SortStraightFlushes(unsorted));
```

...

```
        private List<(int, Hand)> SortStraightFlushes(List<(Hand, List<Card>)> hList)
    {
        var sortedHList = hList.OrderBy(x => x.Item2[0].Value).ToList();
        List<(int, Hand)> output = new List<(int, Hand)>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedHList.Count; i++)
        {
            if(i != sortedHList.Count - 1)
                if (sortedHList[i].Item2[0].Value == sortedHList[i + 1].Item2[0].Value)
                    output.Add((1, sortedHList[i].Item1));
                else
                    output.Add((0, sortedHList[i].Item1));
            else
                output.Add((0, sortedHList[i].Item1));
        }
        return output;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You receive that error on that line?

Comment: That exception has nothing to do with the tuple usage. Show us more of your code.

Comment: @IanKemp here you are

Comment: Does the `Add` method being called in `unsorted.Add((hand, _tempList));` have a parameter named "index"? If not, then that's not the line where that exception is being thrown. The exception stacktrace should show you the exact line number. It's most likely one of the indexer calls that you're making elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how beautiful and accurate it is, but it all worked out the way it did:

```
unsorted.Add((hand, new List<Card>().Concat(_tempList).ToList()));
```